# white-space: nowrap and children with 100% width

Tags: css

I have some text inputs (its count may be various), I need to place them in div, stretch on all width but in one line.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>

div {
    width: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/990xp0xs/)

But it's not working I expected.
I don't want to set inputs' width manually (in px). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this.  input isnt like a div, you have to give it a display value.

```
input {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block; clear:both; display:block;
}
```

Comment: my mistake, i thought you wanted them to be stacked

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to have the inputs stretch equally in accordance with the page.

It's a matter of extending the fluid size of their container, the div, then applying the same fluid size to the inputs (assuming they are each equal) by setting their size to 33%. They will in turn stretch with the full width of the div, which will stretch with the full width of the container (or page) it's in.

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

input {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, it working, but maybe exists solution without manual calculate input's width?

Comment: Consider doing a width:100% on the input, then. You may also want to set a max-width on the parent div. Let me know if that is the desired function.